# Permission Set Blank When Installing Managed Package

Tags: permissions, package

Developed a Permission set based on the SalesForce user license for our managed package. When I install the package as a Sys Admin in customer org, the permission set is blank. Its there, but none of the System permissions included are checked.

Any thoughts why this may be the case? We have a dozen other permission sets with this package and all work fine, but all of those have "none" as the license type vs "SalesForce" for this one. Yes, I know the difference and selected SalesForce here because that is only license type that will use this Permission set.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with packaging Permission Sets in Managed Packages. I found this bug that might be slightly connected to your case:

[Can't install managed package because packaged permission set seems to have lost a read permission](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/cant-install-managed-package-because-packaged-permission-set-seems-to-have-lost)

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know the difference between your org-wide and salesforce licensed permission sets - in general, we block the installation if you try to package a permission set that grants access to a standard resource (e.g. user permission, standard object permission, standard field permission) or you try to package just permission sets and not the metadata that's associated with the permissions (e.g. Foo CRUD won't come over unless Foo is also in the package, just the shell of the permission set will install).

However, I haven't heard of a case where org-wide permission sets do install permissions whereas salesforce permission sets don't. Please provide some examples of the permissions contained in both types of permission sets. thanks!

Comment: If I can respond at some point we will. It was a few months ago now so we moved on and I no longer remember the exact use case. If I recall we had to have support roll back our package so we could "edit" it and reinstall without the above.