# Managed Package Validation Error

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, upload

I'm receiving the following error when uploading a managed package (during the validation stage):

> "Permission Set Name" references "Custom Object" that has M-D relationship with Account.

This is a subsequent release, this custom object has already been released along with all the related fields on the custom object (including the M-D field "Account"). Nothing new has been added to this object for the new release.

This happens for three of my custom permission sets. My custom object absolutely has a master-detail relationship with the Account object. I am not sure what the actual issue is as this "error" is really not giving much information on how to solve the problem.

Has anyone ever seen this error? Can anyone give me any direction on what the root cause of this issue is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Adam Torman's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/cant-install-managed-package-because-packaged-permission-set-seems-to-have-lost) to a somewhat related (but not entirely) question notes:

> We do intentionally block the setting of parent permissions if it's a standard object

By granting any access to a custom object that is M/D to a standard object, that necessitates giving access to that standard object as well.

Managed package permission sets can't grant any access to a standard object, so this is blocked!

Comment: WInner winner! Thanks for the help, I need to remove the M-D field on my custom object and replace it with a lookup field.