# HealthCloud extension can't write HC object. Permissions are ignored

Tags: permission-sets, isv, 2gp, health-cloud, managed-extension

I am developing a **Managed Extension Package** for **HealthCloud**. My app is inserting those native HC objects:

- Board Certification
- Business License
- Healthcare Facility
- Healthcare Provider
- Health Provider NPI

Before we do the DML we check for permission using `Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE)` and also using `Schema.Describe`.

My problem now is that everything works fine until I package this. User with this Perm Set cannot call this code without access error.

I have packaged a Permission Set that grants user write access to those objects but I learned from [this Known Issue](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SbMUAA0) and this[related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/3456/256) packaging such a perm doesn't work. But even when I create a Permission Set outside of the package, I am unable to get this working.

I am also quite sure that the user has all the [right HC permissions and licences](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_permissionset_licenses_assign.htm&type=5).
[image]

***It works perfectly in an Unmanaged context.***

Comment: We also created a Support Case #43990787 for this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot package Permission Sets that permission either standard objects or objects owned by a parent package. See the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm):

> Do they [Permission Sets] include standard object permissions?

> No. Also, you can’t include object permissions for a custom object in a master-detail relationship where the master is a standard object.

and

> Can permission sets in an extension package grant access to objects installed in a base package?

> If the base package is a managed package:
> A permission set in the extension package can't modify access permissions for either the parent objects in the base package or the associated child objects in the extension package.

When you upload your package, permissions that are not available on packaged Permission Sets are silently stripped from your metadata. Your packaged Permission Set simply does not apply those permissions.

You would need to deliver this Permission Set unmanaged, if you wish to do so, and accept the maintenance cycle consequences of that delivery (no upgrades).

Comment: I thought that as well, but it even doesn't work when we create a Permission Set afterwards in the Subscriber org.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Ah, pardon, I didn't understand that note in the question. That behavior doesn't make sense to me. Could well be a bug. I don't know the Health Cloud product well, unfortunately.